# How is F#'s static bound constraints implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, constraints, language-lawyer

In F#, you can perform *black-magic voodoo*<sup>1</sup> and perform static typed constraints to ensure a function is only called on types that have the member constraints. For example:

```fs
module Collection
    let inline init s = 
        let collection = new ^t()
        let add e = (^t : (member Add : 'a -> unit) collection, e)
        Seq.iter add s
        collection
```

This function can be called where a type that has an `Add<'a>` that has the signature `'a -> unit`.

Usage:

```fs
let a:List<_> = Collection.init {1..10}
let b:SynchronizedCollection<_> = Collection.init {1..10}
a |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printf "%A " x)
b |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printf "%A " x)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I'm interested in taking advantage of this kind of functionality in a C# application, but have no idea what kind of pitfalls or trouble I can expect with trying this.

In the interest of avoiding the X-Y problem, I have a WCF generated client that is a hacked together manually edited mess. Not using it is not an option for *reasons*. Many types have member properties with the same name but with different types and no common type, thus my interest in this type of generic constraint.

Is this functionality in F# a viable solution to my problem? How is this implemented? I know C# can do nothing like this...

<sup><sup>1</sup>Not really, I just don't know how, thus the question.</sup>

Comment: If you think of these as text substitutions it seems to be pretty close to what actually happens

Comment: For future reference: [Statically Resolved Type Parameters (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx)

Comment: Just FYI, when you compile this type of "duck typed" code you cannot call this function from C# later. The F# compiler will leave the function there so it shows up in intellisense and such, but the body of the function will have been replaced with "throw new NotSupportedException()", so don't try to call it. So you will not be able to take advantage of this functionality in your C# code unless you build the magic yourself (hack roslyn, use a preprocessor etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In F#, *static member constraints* (which is the name of this voodoo) are implemented by inlining the code of the `init` function each time it is called and generating specialized code for each use.

In general, .NET generic constraints are not rich enough to express member constraints and so this cannot be directly mapped to ordinary .NET generic constraints.

When you write:

```
let a:List<_> = Collection.init {1..10}
let b:SynchronizedCollection<_> = Collection.init {1..10}
```

The compiler will basically replace `Collection.init` with the body of the function and it will replace the call written using static member constraint with a call to the concrete `Add` method of the concrete type. If the call appears in a generic function where the concrete type cannot be determined, it will not be allowed.

I think you could certainly use F# and static member constraints to simplify working with code where many types share properties without any deeper relationship. However, static member constraints are F# specific and there is no way of defining helper functions using them that could then be called from C#. You would have to write larger portion of the client in F# (and perhaps expose nice clean API that completely hides the underlying types).

Comment: Unrelated side note: On happenstance I just ordered your Real World F# book... *It's a small world...* (on the internet)

Comment: @jdphenix Thanks for letting me know :) I hope you'll like it!